# Sticky element with outside element scrolling

Tags: html, css

I simplified to the maximum my problem. I need to make a text which is inside nested divs sticky to the top of the screen
In the snippet provided, the "test" label have to remain on top of the screen until the div is totally out of view.
Is there a css way to make this possible?

```css
        div {
            border : 1px solid;
        }
        .sticky{
            position: sticky;
        }
```

```html
  <h1>1st</h1>
    <div>
        <p class='sticky'>
            test
        </p>
        <br><br> <br><br><br><br> <br><br><br><br> <br><br><br><br> <br><br><br><br> <br><br>
        <br><br> <br><br><br><br> <br><br><br><br> <br><br><br><br> <br><br><br><br> <br><br>
        <br><br> <br><br><br><br> <br><br><br><br> <br><br><br><br> <br><br><br><br> <br><br>
    </div>
    <h1>2nd</h1>
    <div >
        <p class='sticky'>
            test2
        </p>
        <br><br> <br><br><br><br> <br><br><br><br> <br><br><br><br> <br><br><br><br> <br><br>
        <br><br> <br><br><br><br> <br><br><br><br> <br><br><br><br> <br><br><br><br> <br><br>
        <br><br> <br><br><br><br> <br><br><br><br> <br><br><br><br> <br><br><br><br> <br><br>
    </div>
```

Comment: add `top: 0` to `.sticky`

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing `top: 0px` in the `.sticky` class

```
.sticky{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
```